# Parameterized Decorators (Python)

Tags: python-decorators

In the following program, I don't know how wrapper class recognizes arg1 and arg2.

```
def outer_function(function):
    def wrapper(arg1, arg2):
        print("My arguments are: {0}, {1}".format(arg1,arg2))
        function(arg1, arg2)
    return wrapper

@outer_function
def cities(city_one, city_two):
    print("Cities I love are {0} and {1}".format(city_one, city_two))

cities("Nairobi", "Accra")
```

Comment: What does _parametrized decorator_ mean? Your decorator does not receive any parameter besides the decorated function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what happens the moment that the `@outer_function` decorator is applied:

1. `outer_function` is called with the `cities` function as its (only) argument.
2. `outer_function` constructs the `wrapper` function (just now), which can take two arguments and which will internally call the `function` that was passed to `outer_function` -- in this case `cities`.
3. `outer_function` returns that newly constructed `wrapper` function.
4. The new `wrapper` is assigned the name `cities` (in place of the original `cities` function).

Steps 1-4 all happen before the line `cities("Nairobi", "Accra")` is even reached. Here is what happens after that call:

5. `cities` (which now is actually the `wrapper` from before) is now called with arguments `"Nairobi"` and `"Accra"`.
6. The `wrapper` body is executed, which means the arguments `arg1` and `arg2` are printed first, then the `function` (set earlier by the `outer_function` decorator) is called with those same arguments.
7. Since that `function` called by `wrapper` was the original `cities`, its body is now executed, which prints the *"Cities I love..."* line.

Comment: Thank you very much Daniil Fajnberg.